# Nginx, exclude specific URLs for access logs

Tags: nginx

In the access log of my nginx web server I have logs like this:

```
XX.XX.147.5 - - [20/Oct/2022:18:42:59 +0000] "GET /my-subfolder/readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 1496 "-" "EF-Strati-HealthCheck-Client/1.0" "11.16.133.0"
XX.XX.94.5 - - [20/Oct/2022:18:42:59 +0000] "POST /my-subfolder/some-path-to-exclude/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OFsjAj9&sid=2Mufsq23xBh8FRLWAFtD HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "https://www.myapp-example.com/my-subfolder/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "161.165.148.42, 23.205.100.169, 10.74.133.61,11.16.53.0"
```

How can I make a rule to exclude logs a access that has `/socket.io/` in?

Is there a way to put some regex? Like:

```
location ~ ^/socket.io/(.*)$ {
  access_log off;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution you propose? What was the outcome, what did you expect?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/874144/how-to-turn-off-access-log-for-only-a-certain-url-in-this-nginx-configuration

Comment: @Ginnungagap yes, I tried that an other regex, without success

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeBnH.png)

did you try localstroge.debug="*"?
website:enter link description here

Comment: I dont get your answer